# WPF Adorner appear on mouseover animation - what's the best pattern?

Tags: wpf, adorner

An **Adorner** is defined over **part** of an **Image**. The required behavior is as follows:

1. When the mouse is over the image area, including the Adorner area, the Adorner appears.
2. When the mouse leaves the image and Adorner area, the Adorner dissapears.
3. Adorner appearing and disappearing is to be through a fade in / out animation, accordingly.
4. A click on the Adorner area must raise event AdornerClicked
5. A click on the area over the Image which is not hidden by the adorner, must rais ImageClicked.

**A naive implementation**

Attach an animation on the Adorner opacity on the Image's MouseEnter and MouseLeave events, and attach Click events for each. This however causes the Adorner to disappear when the mouse is directly above it (as a MouseLeave is triggered on the Image below), violating requirement number 1.

A possible amendment to the naive implementation is to set IsHitTestVisible=false on the Adorner. However, no clicks are then captured by the Adorner, violating requirement number 4.

**What is the correct pattern which will fulfill the requirements?**

Answer (score 0):

A bit old question but I've just had the same problem and could not find an answer so here's what I've come up with.

So the problem is that the control and its adorner are overlapping and setting the adorner to visible triggers a MouseLeave on the adorned control because it is now covered by the adorner.

The solution is to react on every MouseEnter and MouseLeave on both the adorned control and its adorner(s) and do a hit test manually. If any of them are hit then the adorner(s) should be visible otherwise collapsed.

So you need to be able to get the adorners from the adorned control and vica versa. Getting the adorned control from the adorner is no problem (use the AdornedElement property) but getting the adorners for a control is not provided by the framework (AFAIK) so I use a dictionary that maps my controls to a list of their adorners.

Here's the code inside my Panel-derived class (that contains and arranges my controls and their adorners):

```
private readonly Dictionary<Control, List<Adorner>> _controlToAdornersMap;

...

private void CreateMyControl()
{
    var control = new MyControl();
    control.MouseEnter += OnMyControlMouseEnterOrLeave;
    control.MouseLeave += OnMyControlMouseEnterOrLeave;
    Children.Add(control);
    AddAdorners(control);
}

private void AddAdorners(Control control)
{
    var myAdorner = new MyAdorner(control);
    myAdorner.MouseEnter += OnMyAdornerMouseEnterOrLeave;
    myAdorner.MouseLeave += OnMyAdornerMouseEnterOrLeave;

    var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(control);
    adornerLayer.Add(myAdorner);

    _controlToAdornersMap[control] = new List<Adorner> {myAdorner};
}

private void OnMyControlMouseEnterOrLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestAndSetAdornersVisibility((MyControl)sender, e);
}

private void OnMyAdornerMouseEnterOrLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var adorner = (Adorner)sender;
    HitTestAndSetAdornersVisibility((MyControl)adorner.AdornedElement, e);
}

private void HitTestAndSetAdornersVisibility(MyControl control, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var adorners = _controlToAdornersMap[control];
    var hitTestSubjects = new List<UIElement> { control }.Concat(adorners);
    var hit = hitTestSubjects.Any(i => VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(i, e.GetPosition(i)) != null);

    SetAdornersVisibility(adorners, hit ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed);
}

private static void SetAdornersVisibility(IEnumerable<Adorner> adorners, Visibility visibility)
{
    if (adorners != null)
        foreach (var adorner in adorners)
            adorner.Visibility = visibility;
}
```